# Short story where a man is trying to convince aliens who have classified every possible human story that his relationship is unique and meaningful

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I've hunted for this story for years without success now, including asking on various story-finding forums and searching any keywords I can think of. I have a pretty vivid memory of reading it online about fourteen years ago (about 2010), but I don't have any more specific knowledge of where I found it or how old it was.

From what I remember, the story centers around an encounter between a man and a group of aliens who've created an elaborate categorization system for every aspect of human experience—think something like TVTropes on steroids. Trying to convince them of the richness, depth, and worth of human emotions, he tries emphasizing the personal, human aspects of his romance, but the aliens respond something like "Right, that's a pretty standard Category X31AAC Boy meets Category R42N5S Girl story" and refuse to budge in their dismissal of it.

Stories it is not:

[The Language of Love](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1957-05/page/n39/mode/2up?view=theater) by Robert Sheckley

[The Classification of Love](https://x.com/MattFnWallace/status/1765580491279978966?s=20) by Matt Wallace (per the author; I have not independently examined the story)

[Melancholy Elephants](https://www.baen.com/chapters/W200011/0671319744___1.htm) by Spider Robinson

Comment: It's not a really great fit, but it reminds me a bit of Landscape, With Invisible Hand, a novel adapted to film in 2017. Aliens watch people's experiences for entertainment, but get bored with cliche and/or fakes experiences.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landscape_with_Invisible_Hand

Answer (score 7):

The story you're looking for is part of a blog post by Bob "MovieBob" Chipman on The Escapist, published February 2010 (so your time estimate of fourteen years was bang-on). The story itself is untitled, but the blog post is titled "Trope-a-Dope". An excerpt:

> “Don’t be angry,” said another alien. “We’ve simply been cataloguing for a long time, there’s nothing we’ve not heard. This ‘Abby,’ for example, is a textbook example of what we would index as ‘Female-Type 447.3-B.’ Also sometimes called a ‘Kl’Bo,’ after a character in our popular-fiction who epitomizes the type.”

The story is split in two halves, bracketing a commentary by Chipman on people's obsession with collecting "tropes", and how this type of analysis can sometimes miss the point of narrative media.

[Here's a link](https://www.escapistmagazine.com/trope-a-dope/).